# $IM=mM$. can we say that $I$ is a reduction ideal of $m$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, noetherian, local-rings

**Definition**. Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $I$ a proper ideal, and $M$ a finite $R$-module. An ideal $J\subset  I$ is called a *reduction ideal* of $I$ with respect to $M$ if $JI^nM = I^{n+1}M$ for some (or equivalently all) sufficiently large $n$.

**Question**. Let $(R,m)$ be a Noetherian local ring and $M$ be a finite *faithful* $R$-module. let $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $IM=mM$. can we say that $I$ is a *reduction ideal* of $m$?($I$ is a reduction ideal of $m$ if $Im^n=m^{n+1}$ for some sufficiently large $n$)
if not what conditions can we add (on $I$ or $R$ or...) to can  say $I$ is a *reduction ideal* of $m$?

thank you.

Comment: Have you googled "determinantal trick"? It's also in the book by Swanson and Huneke.

Comment: @Youngsu where in Swanson and Huneke?

Comment: At last; the question answered [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/199243/im-mm-can-we-say-that-i-is-a-reduction-ideal-of-m/200363?noredirect=1#comment497348_200363)